# Casperjs - Cookies are not enabled after thenOpen

Tags: cookies, casperjs

I'm trying to look for a resource in the dom, in order to that I'm following each link of the current page.
The problem is that the first time works perfectly well, but when I start to follow the links I receive "cookies are not enabled". 
I call the script like this: casperjs --cookies-file=/tmp/mycookies.txt  script.js
Here is the script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel: "debug",              // Only "info" level messages will be logged
    verbose:true,
    onError: function(self, m) {   // Any "error" level message will be written
        console.log('FATAL:' + m); // on the console output and PhantomJS will
        self.exit();               // terminate
    },
    pageSettings: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        loadImages:  false,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});
var fs = require('fs');
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4');
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

function followLinks(links) {
    casper.each(links, function(self, link) {
          self.thenOpen(link, function() {
              fs.write("pages/" + link+ ".html", this.getHTML(), 'w'); //for debugging
              if (!lookFor(x('//input[@name="Export"]'))) {
                    var links = getLinks();
                    followLinks(links);
              }
         });
  });
}
casper.start('http://www.url.com', function() {
   this.fill('form#formAuth', { 
        login: 'user@url.com', 
        password:  'apass'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
    followLinks(links);
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: It's important to make sure that you check for typos before posting! theOpen is not a function in the CasperJS lib. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that one of the links is the Logout Link :D. That's why suddenly I got the error